# Get Mirrored FFT Results in Real part

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum

Ok, I'm new to the whole Dsp thing, so sorry if the question is a lame one

I'm trying to extract frequencies from a signal provided by a radio Device (Win Radio G31DDC- IFstream).

The radio provides a 16-bit  signal stream with 50MHz bandwidth and 100MHz sample rate.
when I set my FFT length to 32768 everything seems to work fine and the spectrum view is very similar to bundled application with radio, however the precision of 3051.75Hz (100Mhz/32768) is not enough for my needs, so I increased FFT length to 65536, but at this length I got mirrored data in real part of FFT result.

I suppose I should be able to increase the length to provided sample rate

I'm using NAudio.DSP library for FFT calculations and using Hamming window with length of FFT

Here is the code:

```
_fftLength=32768;
_m = (int) Math.Log(_fftLength, 2.0);

for (var n = 0; n < e.RawData.Length; n ++)
{
   var r=e.RawData[n];
   var i=0;

   _fftBuffer[n].X = (float) (r*FastFourierTransform.HammingWindow(n,_fftLength));
   _fftBuffer[n].Y=i;
}

FastFourierTransform.FFT(true, _m, _fftBuffer);
```

[image: FFT with length 32768]

[image: FFT with length 65536]

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here, please?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "mirrored data"? What do the figures show? Did you increase the size of `_fftBuffer` or just the `_fftLength`?

Comment: @Deve _fftBuffer length and _fftLength are the same, both images are taken from the same signal, the first one with FFT length of 32768 and the second one with 65536, I believe the signal should get more detailed but the result is like I'm using full FFT result not the first half (real) part

Comment: If the input signal is real-valued, its discrete Fourier transform is symmetric like in the lower figure. I would rather ask why the spectrum shown in the upper figure is *not*. Are you sure that you plot the complete FFT result in both cases?

Comment: yes I'm Definitely sure, actually both spectrum figures are generated with the same source code, the only difference is _fftLength value, Is it possible that the real sample rate to be much lower than reported value from radio device (down-sampled) and 100 MHz sample rate is used internally?

Comment: Actually, you're analyzing two different signals, so it is to be expected that their spectra look different. The one spectrum *looks* symmetric which is just normal if you plot the complete FFT output and the input signal is real-valued. But without the rest of the code we can only guess what is going on. Unfortunately, this is not the right place for asking programming questions.

Comment: @Deve Thanks for taking your time, you're right, I didn't want to clutter the question with lots of code, as I used the code in other occasions and it was working fine,  I just have a question, Is it possible that FFT with **length larger than input sample rate** cause the symmetric result in real part (first-half) like second figure (I only draw the first-half (real part) of the result so I normally should not see symmetric results (like the first figure)? thanks.

Comment: The plots look like either an error in one of the plots X dimensions or in the 2nd FFT length or in unpacking the complex result vector.